Dagger Hilt dependency in android studio
while connecting dagger hilt in the new version of android with jetpack compose , I am getting the following error Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose', version: '1.9.22', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:Build file 'C:\Users\KIIT\AndroidStudioProjects\Diyt\build.gradle.kts' line: 2
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose', version: '1.9.22', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Try:


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose', version: '1.9.22', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:


Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose:org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose.gradle.plugin:1.9.22')
Searched in the following repositories:
Google
MavenRepo
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.PluginResolutionResult.getFound(PluginResolutionResult.java:112)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequest(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:192)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:97)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:45)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:219)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:385)
at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:514)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:213)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:124)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:48)
at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:35)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:425)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:46)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:27)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:363)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:756)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:157)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$2(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$10(StateTransitionController.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:195)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:381)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:48)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:42)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:65)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:327)
at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:147)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:140)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:111)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:116)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:79)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$initAction$6(GradleModelFetchAction.java:184)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.initAction(GradleModelFetchAction.java:183)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.doExecute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:138)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$1(GradleModelFetchAction.java:103)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$2(GradleModelFetchAction.java:102)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.withOpenTelemetry(GradleModelFetchAction.java:113)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$3(GradleModelFetchAction.java:101)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.util.GradleExecutorServiceUtil.withSingleThreadExecutor(GradleExecutorServiceUtil.java:18)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:100)
at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:65)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.executeAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:109)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:97)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:81)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:117)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:130)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:267)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:131)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SetupLoggingActionExecutor.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecutor.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SetupLoggingActionExecutor.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:70)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.lambda$execute$0(ForwardClientInput.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.daemon.clientinput.ClientInputForwarder.forwardInput(ClientInputForwarder.java:80)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.lambda$runCommand$0(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:320)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)



Ask Gemini Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose', version: '1.9.22', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources: I have tried the every possible way , but its not solving in the newest android version. Please help me with this


I am expecting it to syn properly and to build the app properly

That plugin only exists for Kotlin versions from 2.0.0 onwards. If you still have problems after upgrading Kotlin to the newest vesrion, please [edit] your question to add your build files so we can have a look.
